# how to scroll to a particular screen location without actually scrolling

Tags: android, scrollview

I have a scrollview inside which I have 5 imageviews say IMV1,IMV2...IMV5 . Now on scrolling,one by one all imageviews are shown in device screen. Now I have a drawer with 5 buttons say 1,2 ..5.

```
Now take us a scenario,
 Currently I am on first imageview. Now when I click on button 5 in the drawer.
 I need IMV5 to show on the screen without scrolling.It can be obtained 
 through smoothScrollBy/scrollTo to y equal to 5*screenHeight. But here it 
 scrolls through all intermediate imageviews. 

Please note,I don't wish to affect scroll feature.For above example,
After I reach IMV5,when I scroll up,it should scroll to IMV4 and so on.
```

Is there any way to obtain it .Please suggest.
Thanks In Advance.

P.S. If you need some more clarification,please let me know.

Comment: so why do you use a ScrollView? do you still need a manual scrolling to see all of images?

Comment: yeah...basic functionality is manual scrolling.But also want to integrate drawer functionality in it which doesn't require to scroll through all imageviews to reach the final imageview.

Comment: ok, so your mission with a SV and required functionality is impossible

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this easily using a `ListView` instead of `ScrollView`.

What you can do is:-

1. Add all the imageviews to a `ListView`.

   - This will fulfill your scrolling requirement, as `ListView` automatically handles scrolling if its content's size is grater than the screen size.
2. Now use the `listView.setSelection(position)` on click of the buttons.

   - It will scroll to the selected imageview without giving the scrolling effect

Hope this helps.

Comment: seems fine answer.But I have to work with ScrollView. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It can be achieved through `ScrollView` too.. All you need to do is get the `View` at that position. Then call `requestFocus()` on the obtained view.

For example:- If you press Button 5, then `IMV5.requestFocus()` will do it for you

Comment: not working.I did. case Button5: IMV1.clearFocus();IMV5.requestFocus();

Comment: try clearing the focus from the button that was pressed. Maybe it is still in focus due to which the imageview cant get the focus..